# Regular expression to match Maven artifcact co-ordinates (Group:Artifact:Version)

Tags: regex, bash, maven, awk

I'm trying to find a robust regular expression that can filter out maven artifact GAV's from a log in Bash using grep and awk.

Here is the current regex I have along with the GAV that breaks it.

I fist grep the log for errors:

```
GAVS="`grep -e "$error" $LOG  | awk '{NF++;while(NF-->1)print $NF}' | grep "[0-9]$" | grep ':'`"
```

This creates a list of GAV's from which I extract a single GAV.

```
GAV="`for gav in $(echo $GAVS | tr " " "\n"); do echo $gav ; done`"
```

This works for most cases but now and again it breaks because of a GAV that looks like this:

```
org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:jar:2.12.0.abcxy-123456
```

That should look like this

```
org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:jar:2.12.0
```

So essentially striping away everything from and including the last period.

Comment: You can do all of the above in a single, simple awk script. Post some small sample input and expected output and we can show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `So essentially striping away the everything from the last period...including the period.`

Use pure BASH way:

```
s='org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:jar:2.12.0.abcxy-123456'
echo "${s%.*}"
org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:jar:2.12.0
```